# How are the seed nodes chosen?

Tags: architecture

I'm currently doing a research project about Bitcoin and I've particularily been investigating the seed nodes and I have two questions about them :

- How are they chosen ? Well, they have to be nodes with high disponibility (bandwith maybe?) but is there any other criterion ?
- Why are some of the nodes located in the network of big companies ? Isn't it a bit contradictory to Bitcoin's spirit to have the ip address of some major financial companies hardcoded in its client ?

Thanks for your answers :)

Ayla

Comment: Specifically, you are asking why were the IP addresses that are served by the hosts in the DNSSeed list chosen over other IP addresses: http://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Satoshi_Client_Node_Discovery.

Comment: I wasn't talking about the one from the DNSSeed list, but about the hardcoded one. Such as : 0xe473042e, 0xb177f2ad, 0xd63f3fb2... (net.cpp)

Answer (score 1):

According to the Bitcoin wiki https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Satoshi_Client_Node_Discovery

> 1. Nodes discover their own external address by various methods.
> 2. Nodes discover their own external address by various methods.
> 3. Nodes makes DNS request to receive IP addresses.
> 4. Nodes can use addresses hard coded into the software.
> 5. Nodes exchange addresses with other nodes.
> 6. Nodes store addresses in a database and read that database on startup.
> 7. Nodes can be provided addresses as command line arguments
> 8. Nodes read addresses from a user provided text file on startup

Because this is peer-to-peer technology the client is usually connected to more than one node at a time. The reference client validates every bit of information it receives. If a financial company was to go rouge and send false or incomplete data the software would realise the data is invalid and rely on the other connected nodes to operate.